# MYSQL column only showing rounded values

Tags: mysql, rounding

I have created a table in mysql as follows:

```
create table scores (id tinyint, score tinyint);
insert into scores VALUES (1, 3.50), (2, 3.65),(3, 4.00),(4, 3.85);
```

but when I am displaying the values, the score column shows all the values as 4.00. I have changed the datatype of the 'score' column to decimal(10,2), float and double(10,2) but with no avail.

How can I solve this,

Thanks

Comment: Instead of the obviously wrong code, post your attempt to fix the problem.

Comment: *when I am displaying the values, the score column shows all the values as 4.00* Your values were rounded during INSERT according to TINYINT datatype. *I have changed the datatype of the 'score' column to decimal(10,2), float and double(10,2) but with no avail.* Your values were damaged already and cannot be repaired. https://dbfiddle.uk/dLBb905i

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't solve this problem without re-inserting the original data into the table because the information about the fractions was never stored in the database.

Obviously, the solution is to use an appropriate dataype. Either you ALTER the TABLE or you reCREATE it, but in any case you'll have to insert the data again:

Approach #1: ALTER TABLE

```
create table scores (id tinyint, score tinyint);
insert into scores VALUES (1, 3.50), (2, 3.65),(3, 4.00),(4, 3.85);
ALTER TABLE scores MODIFY score decimal(10,2);
DELETE FROM scores;
insert into scores VALUES (1, 3.50), (2, 3.65),(3, 4.00),(4, 3.85);
```

Approach #2: recreate the table

```
DROP TABLE scores;
create table scores (id tinyint, score decimal(10,2));
insert into scores VALUES (1, 3.50), (2, 3.65),(3, 4.00),(4, 3.85);
```

Advantage of #1 over #2: you can delete and re-insert subsets of the table's data by adding a WHERE clause to the DELETE statement. You don't need to define all indexes or constraints, again. Advantage of #2 over #1: it's simple in this case.

Comment: Thanks! Dropping the table and then recreating it with decimal datatype worked.